# CDK CustomResource attribute error: Vendor response doesn't contain key in object

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Using CDK, I have an aws custom resource that I want to get a value from its response. Unfortunately, I've been getting the error in the title. A simplified version of [the response](https://github.com/Geekoosh/flyway-lambda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/geekoosh/flyway/response/Response.java) of the lambda that is invoked by the resource is found below:

```
public class Response {

    private ResponseInfo info;

}
```

The lambda handler using this response is [here](https://github.com/Geekoosh/flyway-lambda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/geekoosh/flyway/FlywayHandler.java)

I have tested in AWS Lambda console that the lambda indeed returns json of the form:

```
{
    "info": {...}
}
```

[image]

but when I try to get it (from my custom resource that triggered the lambda) with:

```
flyway_resource.get_response_field("info")
```

I get the error in the title. Any I ideas? How can I view what the custom resource's response actually looks like so that I can use the right keys?

You can view the custom resource definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665986/cdk-custom-resource-response-for-flyway-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

The return json object from your custom resource doesn't have the field "info". I would use boto3 to create the resource and print the response in the console to see how it looks like:

Something like this:

```
    client = boto3.client('Lambda', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
    response = client.invoke(
       FunctionName='string',
       InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
       LogType='None'|'Tail',
       ClientContext='string',
       Payload=b'bytes'|file,
       Qualifier='string'
     )

     print(response)
```

the response of your custom resource seems to be something like this:

{
'StatusCode': 123,
'FunctionError': 'string',
'LogResult': 'string',
'Payload': StreamingBody(),
'ExecutedVersion': 'string'
}

but you can verify it with the boto3 call

boto3 documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html?highlight=lambda#Lambda.Client.invoke